# Generalizing the eigenvalues of the Laplacian on $\Omega$ an interval to $\Omega$ an arc on a circle?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Consider the 1D Dirichlet eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian on the interval $\Omega =[0,1]$:
\begin{align}
u'' + \lambda u & = 0, \quad x \in \Omega, \\
u(0)=u(1) &=0.
\end{align}

The eigenvalues of $-d^2/dx^2$ are given by
$$
\lambda_n = (n\pi)^2,
$$
and the eigenfunctions are given by
$$
u_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x).
$$

Now I would like to generalize this to two cases:

1. **$\Omega$ is an arc on a circle**: The circle is centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and has radius $R$ with endpoints $a$ and $b$.
2. **$\Omega$ is a section of the graph of $y(x)=x^2$**: Again with some endpoints $a$ and $b$.

The reason for this is that I have very little experience with differential geometry but alot of experience with the Helmholtz equation so I think this would be a good approach to learning how to deal with PDEs on manifolds - it seems like these are some of the simplest generalizations we could consider.

So what do I need to do to obtain the eigenvalues (eigenfunctions) for in cases 1. and 2. above? A list of steps to take would be great so I could then try and work out the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this will not work as you expect. The curvature of an arc or a section of a graph is only due to the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The intrinsic curvature is still zero in both cases. So the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are still exactly the same as for the straight interval (in an arc length parametrization).

Comment: So what would be the simplest possible generalization of this Dirichlet eigenvalue problem on the unit interval such that differential geometry is required to obtain a solution, where by solution I mean the solution could be analytic, approximate (in some sense), or numerical? I really want to go through something as explicit as possible, or which can actually be computed, so that I get a 'feel' for the role of various differential geometry concepts.

Comment: I think you need to go up one dimension. One can explicitly compute the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions on a rectangle. A flat torus is almost the same, you get periodic boundary conditions. Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions on the sphere are also known explicitly but look quite different from the flat ones.

Comment: Yes, the spectral properties of the canonical shapes in 2D and 3D can be found through separation of variables. I suppose you could say differential geometry can be used to define the Laplacian for circles/spheres. I think I'm looking for something beyond the canonical shapes but not too general/abstract which is what you find in all the reference books. I'm looking for something still somewhat explicit or numerically computable.

Comment: There are very few examples that are explicitly computable. The few in the reference books are essentially all there is. Maybe you can look at the construction of the heat kernel on manifolds. The construction starts with the heat kernel on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a first order approximation and the generates the heat kernel of the manifold as in infinite series.

Comment: Ok I'll look into that thanks!